# My download manager can not download apk file

Tags: java, android

In my project I can download anything like jpg or png or pdf and other file.
but when I enter a apk link , it download but can not open it.
and it shows that with different folder and I think it is not apk at all, although I give apk link.

here is my code when I get the link to download :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DownloadDataActivity.this);                        
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_custom);
dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_dialog));

// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
final EditText text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
final String link = text.getText().toString();
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (text.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_link), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView showCountries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryData);
            showCountries.setText("");
        } else {

            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(text.getText().toString());
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

            //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
            request.setTitle("");
            //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
            request.setDescription("");
            //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadDataActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Download_Uri+"");

            //Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            showCountries.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.download));
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
```

for example this link:
http://cdn.p30download.com/?b=p30dl-mobile&f=CarX.Drift.Racing.v1.3.8_p30download.com.apk

it shows my just "`cdn.p30download.com`"
and says that it can not be open.

Comment: That URL returns a HTTP 404 File Not Found error.

Comment: no it is direct link to download this apk@CommonsWare

Comment: No, it is not. My original test was flawed; the server actually returns a 301 Moved Permanently response, as determined by using `curl`. Perhaps `DownloadManager` does not follow server-side redirects.

Comment: no the link is ok I can easily download with my device

Comment: `DownloadManager` is not a Web browser. `DownloadManager` will behave more like a command-line utility like `curl`. Just because you can download something using a Web browser does not mean that `DownloadManager` can download it using the same URL.

Comment: is there any way to download all file?